# How do I re-arrange how my loop works?

Tags: node.js

I am working on a message board and i want the new topics to be the first in line. I am using a forEach loop to print out all the Topics but the new ones are going under the old ones. how do i fix this?

my forEach Code

> <% threads.forEach(function(thread){ %>    "><%= thread.subject%>
>     Posted by:
>
> > -
> >
> > ---

Comment: What template language are you using?  Questions here need to supply appropriate context so we don't have to guess what you're doing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that you are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting. If you have a specific question, it should includie details of what you have tried so far and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `reverse`

```
<% threads.reverse().forEach(function(thread){ %> "><%= thread.subject%>
```